# Calling .csv file into Octave

Tags: csv, octave

I have a code written in C++ that outputs a .csv file with data in three columns (Time, Force, Height). I want to plot the data using Octave, or else use the octave function plot in the C++ file (I'm aware this is possible but I don't necessarily need to do it this way).

Right now I have the simple .m file:

```
filename = linear_wave_loading.csv;
M = csvread(filename);
```

Just to practice bringing this file into octave (will try and plot after)
I am getting this error.

```
error: dlmread: error parsing range
```

What is the correct method to load .csv files into octave?

Edit: Here is the first few lines of my .csv file

```
Wavelength= 88.7927 m
Time    Height  Force(KN/m)
0   -20 70668.2
0   -19 65875
0   -18 61411.9
0   -17 57256.4
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It seems like you're doing it right. I'd blame it on your CSV file then. Can you show the first few lines of your file? Also, what Octave version are you using?

Comment: I'm using octave version 3.2.4

The csv file is an excel file and the first few rows/columns look like: 
Wavelength= 88.7927 m
Time Height Force(KN/m)
0 -20 70668.2
0 -19 65875
0 -18 61411.9
0 -17 57256.4

Where I'm guessing that the problem is that hte first few rows I don't want to plot or necessarily read in?

Comment: whoops that's probably too difficult to read...

Comment: I just edited the original post so you can see it a bit better

Comment: that is not a csv file. csv stands for Comma Separated Values and there's no commas on your file. You should use a CSV file writer in your program rather than roll your own. Also, you should update your Octave version (current version is 3.8.2). Yours is a very very old version.

Comment: hmm... I just downloaded octave but I'm using ubuntu 12.04... could that be why the version is so old?? I'll try to update it. Ok in my C++ code, the file is created using ofstream Morison_File ("linear_wave_loading.csv");         //Opening file to print info to
    Morison_File << "Time Height Force(KN/m)" << endl;
    Morison_File << t << " " << z << " " << F_s << endl;

Comment: Because Ubuntu 12.04 was based on Debian testing of 6 months earlier which went through a freeze for more than 1 year before. Octave 3.2.4 was released January 2010, and it has changed a lot since. You can update your Ubuntu to 14.04 (it's also a LTS release), or use [Octave's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable). But that won't fix your problem, because cvsread() reads a CSV file, which your file is not.

Comment: `dlmread` can handle the space separator.  But you may have to remove the header lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using octave 3.8.2

```
>> format long g
>> dlmread ('test.csv',' ',2,0)
ans =

                     0                     0                     0                   -20               70668.2
                     0                     0                     0                   -19                 65875
                     0                     0                     0                   -18               61411.9
                     0                     0                     0                   -17               57256.4
```

General, use dlmread if your value separator is not a comma. Furthermore, you have to skip the two headlines.
Theoretical dlmread works with tab separated values too `'\t'`, but this failes with you given example, because of the discontinuous tab size (maybe it's just a copy paste problem), so taking one space `' '` as separator is a workaround. 
you should better save your .csv file comma separated

```
Wavelength= 88.7927 m
Time    Height  Force(KN/m)
0, -20, 70668.2
0, -19, 65875
0, -18, 61411.9
0, -17, 57256.4
```

Then you can easily do `dlmread('file.csv',',',2,0)`.

You can try my [csv2cell](https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/csv2cell.m)(not to be confused with csv2cell from io package!) function (never tried it < 3.8.0).

```
>> str2double(reshape(csv2cell('test.csv', ' +',2),3,4))'
ans =

                 0                   -20               70668.2
                 0                   -19                 65875
                 0                   -18               61411.9
                 0                   -17               57256.4
```

Usually it reshaped successful automatically, but in case of space seperators, it often failed, so you have to reshape it by your self (and convert to double in any case).

And when you need your headline

```
>> reshape(csv2cell('test.csv', ' +',1),3,5)'
ans =
{
  [1,1] = Time
  [2,1] = +0
  [3,1] = +0
  [4,1] = +0
  [5,1] = +0
  [1,2] = Height
  [2,2] = -20
  [3,2] = -19
  [4,2] = -18
  [5,2] = -17
  [1,3] = Force(KN/m)
  [2,3] = 70668.2
  [3,3] = 65875
  [4,3] = 61411.9
  [5,3] = 57256.4
}
```

But take care, then everything is a string in your cell.

Comment: Thanks Markus! I was able to read the data in. I'm wondering now, if I want to plot the data, say the first column vs. the third column, what would I need to do here? Do I need to then parse the data so that column 1 falls under one variable and column 3 under another? I don't know how to do this yet but I'm just trying to get my head around what needs to be done

Comment: Say `A` is your double Variable.Try
`x = 1:rows(x); plot(x,A(:,1),'r'), hold on, plot(x,A(:,3),'b')`

Answer (score 4):

Your not storing you .csv filename as a string.
Try:

```
filename = 'linear_wave_loading.csv';
```