# Read multi format data in Octave

Tags: matlab, csv, parsing, octave

I have just started learning Octave and am trying to read a `csv` file comprising of data in the form of string, integer and float. Example is shown below

```
a,b,c,d
1,c,10,1234.2
e,2,4,5
```

I initially tried a lot using `csvread`. Some of my examples are below:

```
[val1, val2, val3, val4] = csvread('input.csv', '%s %s %s %s');
```

But I am getting an error like `error: dlmread: error parsing RANGE`

Then using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301419/how-do-i-read-a-delimited-file-with-strings-numbers-with-octave), I made use of `textread` function as shown below:

```
[val1, val2, val3, val4] = textread('input.csv', '%s %s %s %s', 'delimiter', ',');
```

I am able to read the data now, but when I print the values, I am even getting the address of the values like shown below.

```
val1 = 
{
  [1,1] = a
  [2,1] = 1
  [3,1] = e
}
```

Please can somebody help me in

1) Finding out what is wrong in `csvread`.

2) Why `textread` function is returning addresses. How to avoid them?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of dlmread, which is the cause of your error, can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325577/calling-csv-file-into-octave). Note that

```
x = csvread (filename, dlm_opts)
```

is equivalent to

```
x = dlmread (filename, "," , …)
```

The item returned by textread

```
val1 = 
{
  [1,1] = a
  [2,1] = 1
  [3,1] = e
}
```

is a  [cell array of strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Cell-Arrays-of-Strings.html). Cell arrays are used, as a matrix must be composed of vectors of equal length, which is not the case, when one operates one words of variable size. If one would have stored words in a matrix, all rows/columns would have had to be "padded", to be as long as the longest word stored.

To convert an element at a specific index of a cell array (val1) to a vector you employ [cell2mat](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/cell2mat.html)

```
vec=cell2mat(val1(index));
```